# Convert SQL geography to C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqlgeography

What is the C# equivalent of this geospatial T-SQL code?

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326);
SET @h = geography::Point(47.653, -122.358, 4326)

SELECT @g.STIntersects(@h)
```

I am trying to find a point in a polygon using the `SqlGeometry` data type -- and can with the above T-SQL; but I do not understand how to achieve equivalent C# code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Geo functions from SQL Server 2008 to C# (latitude and longitude points inside or outside polygon/map area)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448054/geo-functions-from-sql-server-2008-to-c-sharp-latitude-and-longitude-points-ins)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
public bool OneOffSTIntersect()
{
    var g =
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(
            new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars(
                "POLYGON((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))"), 4326);
    // suffix "d" on literals below optional but explicit
    var h = Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Point(47.653d, -122.358d, 4326);

    // rough equivalent to SELECT
    System.Console.WriteLine(g.STIntersects(h));

    // Alternatively return from a C# method or property (get).
    return g.STIntersects(h);
}
```

MSDN's [SqlGeography Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography_methods.aspx) page links to info on each of the C# equivalents to the critical calls in your T-SQL - e.g. `STIntersects`.

Comment: `// rough equivalent to SELECT`  :-)

Comment: @Tim:  Funny, last night this just came out the way I thought it not knowing the OP's general level of C# knowledge or context to use the translated code; but today this strikes me as pretty funny too. :)  Thanks for pointing it out.