# SQL Server geography result format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, geography

Using SQL Server Management Studio:

```
declare @g geography
set @g = geography::Point(-77.1851436,39.1065236,4326)
select @g
```

returns

```
0xE6100000010C14C48A64D94B53C04820B990A28D4340
```

What format is this result? I know that it is not STAsBinary() - that returns

```
0x01010000004820B990A28D434014C48A64D94B53C0
```

Is there a way to create the 0xE61... value using C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is special binary format defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee320529.aspx) (you may download PDF there if interested about details of that format). You can create such value in C# like this (reference `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` assembly):

```
var pt = SqlGeography.Point(-77.1851436, 39.1065236, 4326);    
var binary = pt.Serialize().Value;
var hexString = "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(binary).Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for sharing your insight.

Answer (score 2):

result is type of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Point

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456365/convert-sql-geography-to-c-sharp)